# How can i get the original values of specific column of cachedrowset?

Tags: java, jdbc, cachedrowset

it returns the current value of the select column, all i need is to return the original value for checking if the value really changed.

```
while(rs.next()){
    if (rs.rowUpdated){
        String strOrigVal = "";
        rs.getOriginalRow();
        strOrigVal = rs.getString("col1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ResultSet getOriginalRow()
>                      throws SQLException
> ```

```
while(rs.next()){
  if (rs.rowUpdated){
      String strOrigVal = "";
      ResultSet ors = rs.getOriginalRow(); //you should catch the return value
      if(ors.next()){ //move to the first cursor
        strOrigVal = ors.getString("col1");
      }    
  }
}
```

Comment: do i need to set the cursor position? whenever i called ors.getString("col1") there is an exception "SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid cursor position"

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Yes, you need to set the cursor position just like other ResultSet(ors.next()) to point to the first element.

Comment: last question, in ors variable only the current row of rs will be stored?

Comment: I do not try whether there more than one row, but according to the Java API document, It only return the current row.